# Javascript Regex Split After Certain Word or Number

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex:

```
"12 DOse Flaschentomaten".split(/(\d+(?:\s(?:Dose|TL|EL)){0,})\s+(.*)/gi)
```

Gives me in the regex tool (https://www.regex101.com/) two groups:

```
12 DOse  
Flaschentomaten
```

Which is what I want.

But in the javascript console this array

```
["", "12 DOse", "Flaschentomaten", ""]
```

Side Questions:
If I want to use an external array for the filter words do I have to define it as a string:
var filterWords = "sp, ts, spoon";
Can I use the i tag for not case sensitive also only on groups?

Comment: What is the "main" question ? if you're asking why you get this result, it's because you are splitting your string I guess, regex101 only get the matches of your regex

Comment: what's the issue you've hit here? is the question how to get your array of results into a string?

Comment: The issue/main question is how to split phrases like 1 Dose Banana, 1 Banana or 1 TL Banana into two strings. The first should contain the 1 + an optional Word the second should contain the rest (in the example Banana). Unfortunately my regex seems to split the phrase into 4 pieces.

Comment: I could use `array.shift()` and `array.pop()` afterwards but why does it add the empty strings in the first place/ and how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want `match`, not `split`:

```js
m = "12 DOse Flaschentomaten".match(/(\d+(?:\s(?:Dose|TL|EL))?)\s+(.*)/i)
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(m,0,3));
```

Add `m.shift()` to remove the first element (=the whole match).